# Injective resolution for right derived functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

This question is base on my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159547/why-is-the-derived-tensor-product-only-defined-for-bounded-above-derived-categor/159549#comment408017_159549), and I repeat it here:

Suppose $X$ is a projective variety and $D^{+}(X)$ is the derived cateogry of bounded below complexes of sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Let $F$ be a sheaf, and I want to define a derived tensor $\otimes F: D^{+}(X) \to D^{+}(X)$ as follows:

Suppose $G^{\bullet} \in D^{+}(X)$, and I lift it to the homotopy category $K^{+}(X)$ (also denoted by $G^{\bullet}$), let $I^{\bullet} \in K^{+}(X)$ be a complex of **injectives** which is quasi-isomorphic to $G^{\bullet}$(this can always obtain because $G^{\bullet}$ is bounded below). Then tensoring $F$ to $I^{\bullet}$, we have a complex $F\otimes I^{\bullet}$. Finally, map this complex to $D^{+}(X)$. My question is, is this the correct way to define the derived tensor $\otimes F$?

I know this is weird, because $\otimes F$ is right exact and one supposed to use flat resolution. However, here is my reason why I got the above procedure:

By Chapter I Corollary 5.3 (page 56) of the book ["Residues and Duality"](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN496067613&DMDID=DMDLOG_0011&LOGID=LOG_0011&PHYSID=PHYS_0057), if $A,B$ are two abelian categories, and $F:A \to B$ is an additive functor, and assume $A$ has enough injectives, then the derived functor $\mathbf{R}^{+}F$ exists.

The construction can be found in Theorem 5.1 loc.cit. The main fact is although injective objects are not $\otimes F$-acyclic, if a complex of injectives $I^{\bullet}\in K^{+}(X)$ is acyclic (i.e. $H^i(I^{\bullet})=0$ for all $i$), then $F \otimes I^{\bullet}$ is also acyclic (i.e. $H^i(F \otimes I^{\bullet})=0$ for all $i$).

Please correct me if anything is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand, but my advice is really to revisit some basic points. Why do you think this is a RIGHT derived functor????? derived tensor product is a LEFT derived functor.

Comment: I see where I was wrong. But why derived tensor has to be a left derived functor? It could well be a right derived functor as I defined -- this make sense, but maybe meaningless -- I don't have any idea about this...

Comment: Well, yes, in this way you the right derived functors of tensor products. But since Tensor products are right exact, its $i$-th right derived functor is identically zero, save for $i = 0$.

Comment: You may be interested in [this paper](https://math.mit.edu/research/undergraduate/urop-plus/documents/2018/Beuchot.pdf), which investigates the consequences of treating tensor/hom as a left/right derived functor, *anti*-respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are certainly allowed to do this and you will get a **right** derived functor because you are looking at resolutions $G^\bullet \to I^\bullet$ (note how the arrow is pointing to the right!). This works because any two injective resolutions $I^\bullet$ of $G^\bullet$ are homotopy equivalent, so you can use this to compute the right derived functor of absolutely *any* functor.

However, the derived tensor product is defined as a **left** derived functor.

Maybe this will help: the derived tensor product can be computed by taking a K-flat resolution in either variable. Thus you can first take a K-flat resolution $F^\bullet \to F$ (if $F$ is a sheaf this can be just your usual bounded above complex of flat modules resolving $F$) and then $Tot(F^\bullet \otimes G^\bullet)$ computes the derived tensor product. You don't even have to replace $G^\bullet$; in fact, since now $F^\bullet$ is K-flat you can reoplace $G^\bullet$ by any quasi-isomorphic complex and you get the same answer in the derived category.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see where I was wrong: $\otimes F$ can be used to define a right derived functor, but we usually define it as a left derived functor, and they two may not the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a little confusion between right and left derived functors. Let me repeat the definition using the language of Kan extensions. In the following for any abelian category $A$ we will write $D(A)$ for its derived category (i.e. the localization of the category of complexes to weak equivalences). Let also $\iota_A:A\to D(A)$ be the natural inclusion.

If $A,B$ are abelian categories and $F:A\to B$ is an additive functor we say that a functor $RF:D(A)\to D(B)$ equipped with a natural transformation $\iota_B \circ F \to RF \circ \iota_A$ is the **right derived functor** if it is universal among those functors.

We can also define its **left derived functor** $LF$ in the same way, but with a map $LF \circ \iota_A \to \iota_B \circ F$. There is a deep difference between those two concepts. You seem to think that if a functor has both a left derived functor and a right derived functor those are equal, but I do not see of any obvious reason why this should be true.

In fact left and right "derived" functors is, in my opinion, a bad terminology (a better one would be maybe left and right "approximations") with which we are unfortunately stuck.

The main difference here between a flat resolution and an injective resolution is that flat resolutions map *into* your object, while injective resolutions map *out* of your object.

Moreover I really don't think that it is true that if $I^\bullet$ is an acyclic complex of injective modules then $I^\bullet\otimes M$ is acyclic for all $M$. If it is I will be very surprised (I tried for a while to come up with a counterexample but I wasn't able to).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I see where I was wrong. However, for the statement $I^{\bullet}$ is acyclic then $I^{\bullet} \otimes M$ is also acyclic, you can prove by using "Residues and Duality" Chapt I, Lemma 4.5 Page 41.

Comment: If $I^\bullet$ is an acyclic complex of injective objects, bounded below, it is *contractible*, i.e. homotopy equivalent to the zero complex. Since any additive functor (exact or not) has to preserve homotopy equivalences, it follows that in such a case $I^\bullet \otimes M$ is acyclic as well.

Comment: For unbounded complexes, the claim is false. Consider the acyclic complex $\cdots \stackrel{2}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/4 \stackrel{2}{\to} \cdots$ of $\mathbb{Z}/4$-modules. This is a complex of projective modules (so, in the dual category, it's a complex of injective objects). But tensoring it with $\mathbb{Z}/2$, one obtains a complex which has cohomology in every degree. (This counterexample is in Gelfand/Manin.)

Comment: For the less initiated, could you say briefly the connection to Kan extensions?

Comment: @PrimeRibeyeDeal Let $K(A)$ be the homotopy category of complexes (i.e. complexes and homotopy classes of maps). Then it is easy to see that any additive functor $F:A→B$ induces a functor $F:K(A)→K(B)$. The left derived functor $LF$ is just the right Kan extension of the composition $K(A)→K(B)→D(B)$ along the projection $K(A)→D(A)$. Similarly the right derived functor is the left Kan extension. This is Deligne's approach to derived functors (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05S7)